# If a liberated photoelectron has 0 kinetic energy, what will happen?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

If a photoelectron was liberated from the material it was in, and all of the energy transferred to the electron from the photon was used to overcome the bonds in the material (where hf = work function) then the electron will have 0 kinetic energy. In this case, will the electron just be attracted to the positively charged nucleus or will something else happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electron is freely moving outside the material. In principle it left behind a positive charge and Gauss law tells us that there then is an electric field outside the piece of material. However, this is a very weak effect due to the macroscopic distance between the two charges and, besides, can be considered as included in the work function.